# Loop values in variable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

yesterday I asked question which have been answered correctly. Now I want spend more time to understand that function which answered yesterday. In that function loop is adding value '7' in 'num' variable. I want to know how its adding value in 'num'.

```
var Arr = [ 'h78em', 'w145px', 'w13px' ]

function stringToNum(str){
  num = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) 
    if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') 
      num = num * 10 + parseInt(str[i]);
  return num;
}

alert(stringToNum(Arr[0]));
​
```

here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8WwHh/)

Comment: mdas rules apply you multiplied num by 10 first before adding the parse value, therefore 0 * 10 + 78 = 78

Comment: if you remove *10 + parseInt(str[i]); and then alert num it will return 7, i want to know how it is 7 is passing to num variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given code, when the function is called, the if condition checks for each string in the passed value and when the variable is a number, the following code is executed

```
   if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') 
      num = num * 10 + parseInt(str[i]);
```

so in the given string, the first number occurs is `7`. Since the value of `num` is initially zero the value of num will be,

```
 num=( 0 *10) + 7
```

so `num=7` in the first occurence of the number. On the second occurence of a number, `ie 8`

the value of num will be,

```
  num=(7*10)+8
```

hence the value is `78`

Comment: Thanks a lot sir ji. You have very nice way to explain.

Answer (score 1):

The below function will be much simpler.

```
function stringToNum(str) {
  return +str.replace(/\D/g, '');
}
```

***Update:***

With your code:

```
init : num = 0
met 7: num = 0 * 10 + 7 -> num = 7
met 8: num = 7 * 10 + 8 -> num = 78
```

Comment: i dont want new answer for the same, i just want understand this

Comment: @amit What is the part you can't understand?

Comment: @amit It's much better to get rid of non-digits using regex than to iterate over the string parsing each digit individually (+1 @xdazz). It's cleaner, easier to understand at a glance, and should perform better (certainly as the string grows longer)

Answer (score 1):

1 iteration: `num = 0; // h`

2 iteration: `num = 0 * 10 + 7; // 7`

3 iteration: `num = 7 * 10 + 8; // 8`

4 iteration: `num = 78; // e`

5 iteration: `num = 78; // m`